# Problems with 10k-tools : duplicate answers (auto):

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions, 10k-tools

Second time I see this today.

The first time it was OK, the only thing I needed was an option where you can confirm the assumption. Like

> [ * ] This is a duplicate

Can only confirm with "not an answer" or similar. But it can easily be a good answer, even if it is a duplicate. The second time was not so OK, because the reference is a ***deleted*** answer :

The answer suspected as being a duplicate -> **https://stackoverflow.com/a/22995243/1407478**
The answer that it is being duplicating -> **https://stackoverflow.com/a/22994981/1407478**

The author is the same, so not a total ripoff. Is reuse of a deleted answer really a duplicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The duplicate answer flags are when one person goes around and posts the same answer to a bunch of questions.  It's usually a sign of spammers.  If the answer isn't spam/utter garbage, it's often a sign the questions are duplicates.  If they aren't, it's generally a sign that the answers aren't tailored to the question at hand, and they should be (this is where someone takes the time to write up a really detailed answer about some broad issue and then goes around posting it to tons of questions that simply mention FooBar).

The goal here isn't really to catch plagiarism, as you seem to have expected.

Comment: I know that. But here you have a reference to a **self** **deleted** answer, posted by a user with 2,430 reps. Doesnt smell like spam or robos to me.

Comment: @davidkonrad They're automated flags, not user flags.  There are false positives.  The odds of it being a useful flag are high enough that it's work looking into.

Comment: Yes, I KNOW it is automated, thats why I raise the issue here on meta!

Comment: So what do you want to hear?  That this one flag isn't worth acting on?  That these automated flags should be removed?  What?  I described what the goal of these flags is designed to draw attention to.  If you don't see evidence of that, then that's fine.

Comment: The user may have posted this answer, deleted it, and then have seen an almost similar question and posted the "original". Without evil intent. It cannot be a duplicate, since the answer not is posted twice for the enduser.

Comment: @davidkonrad Sure.  If, after looking at the posts, you don't see anything wrong with any of the flagged content, then that's fine.  This is in invalid flag.

Comment: I want to hear the auto / community-user or whatever not should consider deleted questions in the "duplicate"-algortihm. If you post a perfect answer, delete it, and then repost it in another context, then it is a duplicate?

Comment: @davidkonrad Note that one answer wasn't deleted before the other was posted; at one point in time the same post was active on two different answers, that is likely when the flag was generated.

Comment: Okay, that completely ruin the prerequisities of my question :-( Thank you. If that is the deal, my q is not valid.

Comment: I'll check your answer, but still think there should be a specific "agree with this is a duplicate" option.